# Системы автоматизации интерфейсов пользователя в линуксе

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, автоматизация

Какие системы автоматизации интерфейсов пользователя существуют для линукса(debian, ubuntu), на практике ??

Просто столкнулся с такой проблемой что по сути sikulix для линукса увы не поддерживается, издатель заявляет что поддерживается но на практике как я понял работает не у многих. Также упомяну про Actiona  которая даже не имеет простейшего примера из за чего я даже не понял как за неё взяться.

Вот по этому хочу узнать про доступные простому обывателю системы автоматизации интерфейсов пользователя в линуксе. Желательно чтоб поддерживала один из языков которые мне интересны (Qt, C#)

[image: картинка из статьи https://habr.com/ru/company/yandex/blog/336476/]
картинка из статьи https://habr.com/ru/company/yandex/blog/336476/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В линуксе по моему результату есть три системы автоматизации интерфейсов пользователя :

1. [routinebot](https://www.routinebot.com/)
2. Actiona ( так и не понял как она работает)
3. Sikuli (у меня так и не запустилась)
4. [Squish IDE](https://www.froglogic.com/tag/squish-ide/) (установился весьма не плохо, есть документация)

---

*Также есть [неплохая статья](https://xakep.ru/2011/06/11/57412/), и стоить упомянуть что я не указал системы которые работают по VNC*

Comment: routinebot какая то странная система, ссылка только через почту, линукс не поддерживат (упоминания не нашел). Squish IDE  - такая же мутная программа. Ссылки на скачать нет (только через регистрацию). По скриншотам вроде только мак поддерживат. Actiona  - похоже что оно работает, но их сайт уже давно лежит, исходнкики не трогались лет 6. Поэтому, ответ на свой же вопрос очень и очень похож на наивный спам.

Comment: @KoVadim routinebot  я через вине установил.Squish IDE  регистрируешься и качаешь , норм я справился с этим. Только вот нормальных примеров увы нету и это даа , проблема, именно это я считаю основной проблемой, почему эти системы Sikuli будут проигрывать.